# Doctrine ZFA\Exclude fields are shown on form on IIS

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2, iis-7.5

We have a project using Zend Framework along with Doctrine. We use the doctrine form annotations to generate our forms and it works very well on our apache/linux server.

However, when we migrate our application to the client server, a windows running IIS 7.5, the entity properties marked with ZFA\Exclude are being displayed in the form while they should not be there at all normally.

Does anybody have encountered this error? Yes there is a [similar post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1838052.aspx?type%20hidden%20controls%20are%20being%20shown%20sql%20server%202008%20R2%20IIS7%20MS%20Server%202008) and we try to install the patch KB2600217 as described, but this patch is not applicable to the server of our client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was pretty simple : we had a mix of tabs and spaces in the entity file. Everything was going okay until we deployed to a Windows machine were the annotations weren't parsed completely. We just converted everything to spaces and it fixed everything.